# SQL Sorting data in ascending having alphanumeric characters with symbols

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(SortThis VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES('0/A'),('1/1A1'),('1/10A1'),('002/10A'),
('1/2B4'),('1/2B22'),('2/a'),('2'),('3'),('3/a'),('2/12'),('3-10/ b'),('10'),('4'),
('10-2'), ('10(a)'), ('5-1/4'),('15 A'),('5-3/14B'),('19E/4'), ('31/1A'),('24');

--SELECT * FROM @mockup ORDER BY SortThis --alphanumerical sorting

SELECT m.SortThis
FROM @mockup m
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(SortThis,'/','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) A(Casted)
ORDER BY A.Casted.value('/x[1]/text()[1]','nvarchar(10)') --pick the first value as number
        ,A.Casted.value('/x[2]/text()[1]','nvarchar(10)') --pick the second number as string

----
```

From this I want to sort in ascending order, like 1 series and then 2 series and then 3 series from that data provided.

Expected output:
1/10A1
1/1A1
1/2B22
1/2B4
2
2/12
2/a
3
3/a
3-10/ b
4
5-1/4
5-3/14B
10
10(a)
10-2
11
15 A
19E/4
31/1A

Comment: Is that the wanted order? (BTW, most people here want sample data as formatted text, not images.)

Comment: The "mistake" is that you have assumed that the numbers `1`,`2` and `10` would have the same sort order as the strings  `'1'`,`'2'` and `'10'`. This isn't the case. In string terms, the order would be `'1'`,`'10'`,`'2'`, as `'2'` > `'1'`. Could you also have a value like `'2/10A4'`?

Comment: Sample data 1/8A2
1/8B,
1/9,
1/9,
1/9A,
1/9A1,
1/X28,
10,
10,
10, 2,2A

Comment: @Larnu, i think you meant `'2' > '10'`. It's true that string 2 is greater than string 1, but it doesn't really reinforce the point

Comment: I did actually mean `'2' > '1'`, @CaiusJard. String sort order is based on left to right characters, and both `'1'` and `'10'` start with the character `'1'`.  *(Also `L a r n u`)*

Comment: Yes, but `2 > 1` just as `'2' > '1'` so it's not as persuasive an argument as `'2' > '10' is true but 2 > 10 is false` if you're trying to highlight the difference between string sorting and numerical. I see the point you're making (any string starting with 2 is greater than any string starting with 1) but the OP might not, because he hasn't a clue why his data isn't sorting correctly

Comment: I realise these aren't in the sample you have provided, however, we need to cover all bases. What should the sort order be for the following values? `'1/1A1', '1/10A1','1/2B4','1/2B22','1/A7'`

Comment: `Select ascii('1/1A1')` and `Select ascii('1/10A1')` (as per OP) both return 49!

Comment: I like to bring 2 before 10

Comment: @JonTout as per the documentation ([ASCII (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ascii-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)): *"Returns the ASCII code value of the leftmost character of a character expression."*. So yes, `ASCII('1')` and `ASCII('1')` should return the same values.

Comment: That's my point @Larnu. If (and why) the OP wants to sort by the ASCII value of the string, I reckon they'd need a function to sum the ascii value of each character in the string and sort based on that total.

Comment: That's not going to give them the result they want. they want `'10'` to have a value > `'2'`. Sorting by the `ASCII` value of each character in sequence would be the same as what they have now.

Comment: @user1887367 Thx for providing your sample data in a consumable format. Now please add the expected output and explain the rules

Comment: @user1887367, ... *and explain the rules*... This might be clear for you...

Answer (score 1):

You can order by ASCII:

```
SELECT doorno, ASCII(doorno) FROM testdata WHERE doorno ORDER BY ASCII(doorno)
```

Reference:
[SQL Sorting by ascii values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53631424/sql-sorting-by-ascii-values)

Answer (score 0):

It might help to split the string. So you can use decide whether to treat a fragment as number or as a string (alphanumeric sorting). Try it out:

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(SortThis VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES('0/A'),('1/1A1'),('1/10A1'),('002/10A'),('1/2B4'),('1/2B22'),('1/A7');

SELECT * FROM @mockup ORDER BY SortThis --alphanumerical sorting

SELECT m.SortThis
FROM @mockup m
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(SortThis,'/','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)) A(Casted)
ORDER BY A.Casted.value('/x[1]/text()[1]','int') --pick the first value as number
        ,A.Casted.value('/x[2]/text()[1]','nvarchar(10)') --pick the second number as string
```

Comment: It works with symbol / content data.. but not like other characters like 10-2, 10(a), 5-1/4,15 A,5-3/14B,19E/4, 31/1A, 24,H793...

Comment: @user1887367, Sorry, my magic crystal ball did not work properly... Really, how do you expect anybody here to know your data? Your question doesn't show any of the examples above... If you want help you must provide reduced but realistic sample data. Read [mcve]. You can use my `DECLARE` and `INSERT` to provide your data in a consumable format. We hate pictures here... Share what you've tried and state the expected output.